# Custom attribute to validate file type on upload form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to perform checking on an uploaded file in my form to verify that it is either a CSV or TXT file.

I've created a custom attribute, as below:

```
public class ValidateUploadAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var file = value as HttpPostedFileBase;
        if (file == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (file.ContentType != "text\\CSV" || file.ContentType != "text\\TXT")
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

And then created a view model that looks like this

```
[ValidateUploadAttribute(ErrorMessage = "Please select a TXT or CSV file")]
public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
```

And my `HttpPost` controller looks like

```
public ActionResult Upload(UploadViewModel uploadViewModel, string site)
{
    ...
}
```

So, everything is good up until this point.  The `ValidateUploadAttribute` is called and passes or fails with a bad file type.  The problem is that this upload form goes into a partial view, which sits inside of another view that's model is not of type `UploadViewModel`, so I can't call something like `@Html.ValidateFor(x => x.File)` (i.e., the validation fails but doesn't actually do anything because I can't put the validation helper into the view)

**The partial view**

```
<div id="upload-form" class="div-center content-div" style="margin-top: 15px;">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Association", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "upload-form"}))
{

    <input type="file" name="File" style="width: 79%;"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload for Add" style="width: 19%;"/>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the view model for your action, instead of including `File`, can you include a `UploadViewModel` property instead?

```
class MyViewModel
{
  // Other data

  public UploadViewModel Upload { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can give your partial view a specific model type:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.UploadViewModel
```

Once you do this, you can add the `@Html.ValidationFor(m => m.File)`.

In your encompassing view, render your partial view, but also pass in the model:

```
@Html.Partial("_MyPartialView", Model.Upload)
```

An alternative is to put your partial view in an `EditorTemplates` subfolder and rename it to match your `UploadViewModel` class name (eg. UploadViewModel.cshtml).  Then you can use the following to render your partial view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Upload)
```

It will automatically find the view.